# Receiving list indices must be integers or slices error

Tags: python

I'm new to learning python and trying to calculate something. I'm getting a TypeError, any help would be awesome: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
    names = ['Alex', 'Ari','Dylan', 'Parker', 'Quinn', 'Ethan', 'Nick', 'Sarah', 'Christy']

import requests

name_check = {}
name_check = []
test = {}
new = {}

for index in range(len(names)):
    name_check['name'] = names[index]

    name_test = requests.get('https://api.genderize.io/',params=name_request).json()

    new = {}
    new['gender'] = name_test['gender']
    new['probability'] = name_test['probability']
    new['count'] = name_test['count']

    test[name[index]] = new

test
```

Comment: At what line are you getting the error?

Comment: Why are you assigning `name_check = {}` and then immediately doing `name_check = []`?

Answer (score 1):

```
name_check = {}
name_check = []
```

You are redefining `name_check` to a list, so `name_check['name']` will not work. You should delete the second line.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm now getting an error on this line, any ideas?:
test[name[index]] = new

IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 1):

This type of using lists are wrong.
As you see here `name_check['name']` is an erroneous statement, since you cannot consume strings as an index for lists.

You can learn how to make use of lists properly from link below:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str**

Because on Line # 11

name_check['name'] = names[index] # on line 11

is creating a problem. As on line #6 and line #7 , there are conflicting definitions

```
name_check = {} #First initializing it as dictionary
name_check = [] # Then naming same as List
```

so the line # 11 is interpreting name_check as list as opposed to a dictionary.
Therefore, when you are trying to put 'name' key in name_check variable it throws an exception saying that 'it is expecting an integer instead of string'